# Reaction not being triggered by nested observables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mobx, mobx-react

I have a observable class with nested observable properites:

```js
class TodoItem {
  @observable name: string = "";
  @observable completed: boolean = false;

  @action
  setCompleted(value: boolean) {
    this.completed = value;
  }

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}

class TodoList {
  @observable todos: TodoItem[] = [];

  @action
  addTodo(todo: TodoItem) {
    this.todos.push(todo);
  }

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}
```

When I am trying to modify a `TodoItem` in the `todos` properties of a `TodoList` instance, the `reaction` block is not triggered:

```js
reaction(
  () => store.todos,
  (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }
);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-reaction-81q33n

Expected: when toggling the todo, the todo list should be printed to the console

Happeded: Nothing is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually react to the change of some observable value you need to use it, or `dot into` it or `touch` it, whatever you call it. Your `reaction` only tracks changes to the `store.todos` array itself, so if you change this array it will fire.

It won't fire if you modify some item inside of it obviously, because this reaction does not `touch` or use them in any way.

If you want to react to all and every change inside `store.todos` you can use `JSON.stringify` or MobX method `toJS`, like that:

```
reaction(
  () => JSON.stringify(store.todos),
  (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }
);
```